# Can't find -lfftw when compiling a Fortran example

Tags: linux, fortran, fft, gfortran, fftw

My aim is just to test FFTW on a one dimensional example. I've already installed everything, following the instructions. When I try to compile:

```
gfortran fftg.f90 -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3
```

The terminal is giving the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld : can't find -lfftw3
```

I don't understand why because it is installed on my compute and when I'm searching for it, the library of FFTW is here

```
 /usr/local/lib$ ls
cmake  libfftw3.a  libfftw3.la  pkgconfig  python2.7  python3.4  R  site_ruby
```

I did not find any answer. Where the error is coming from? For more details, this is my code (taken from http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~wttsai/fortran)

```
program example

implicit none
include 'fftw3.f90'
integer, parameter :: N=16
integer*8 :: PLAN_FOR,PLAN_BAC
real*8,dimension(N) :: IN,OUT,IN2
real*8 :: xj
integer :: j,k,mode
real*8, parameter ::twopi=2.*acos(-1.)
!Discrete data of function f(x)=cos(x)+0.2*sin(2x)
do j=0,N-1
    xj=twopi*real(j)/real(N)
    IN(j)=cos(xj) +0.2*sin(2.*xj)
end do

write(*,*) "Original data"
do j=1,N
   write(*,100) j,IN(j)
end do
100 format(i4,f12.5)

! Forward transform

call dfftw_plan_r2r_1d(PLAN_FOR,N,IN,OUT,FFTW_R2HC,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
call dfftw_execute_r2r(PLAN_FOR,IN,OUT)
OUT=OUT/real(N,KIND=8)         

! Normalize
write(*,*) "Fourier coefficient after forward FFT"

do k=1,N
   mode=k-1
   if(k > N/2+1) mode=N-k+1
   write(*,100) mode,OUT(k)
end do

call dfftw_destroy_plan(PLAN_FOR)
end program example
```

Comment: You say `-lfftw3` but the error is `-lfftw`. So which one is correct? Please make sure you copy everything correctly and exactly. Use copy and paste. How did you setup the paths? Do you use `$LIBRARY_PATH`? Do you use `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? How did you install the library? Did you do it manually?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the correct '-lfftw3'. I've install everything following the easy instructions given by fftw. ( Just 'configure', 'make', 'make install ' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally have to setup the paths too, but I see you are using `-L/usr/local/lib` instead. That should suffice for the linking (not necessarily for running).

But your compiled FFTW is static (`.a`) and you are compiling dynamically. You can try compiling with `-static`. If you need to link dynamically you need to install also the dynamic version (`.so`) of the library (i.e. NOT use `-enable-static` in `configure`).

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand what you really by " setup the path " ( it was not mentioned in the instructions ) or dynamic/static compilation. I've tried to compile   `gfortran fftg.f90 -static/usr/local/lib -lffw3` but it does not work.

Comment: Never say "it doesn't work", it tells nothing. Tell what happened. You must have a space between -static and /usr. You will have to study more about what static and dynamic means and how to setup linker paths, I cannot write a large lesson here.

Comment: `gfortran fftg.f90 -static /usr/local/lib -lffw3 ` and the terminal is giving me 
` fftg.f90:4: Error: Can't open included file 'fftw3.f90'  ` . I don't know why because I have the file fftw3.f90.

Comment: Because you also missed the `-L` before the path. I didn't notice you deleted it. You can see the compiler manual about how to use these options. I normally.put -static before the source file name.

Comment: And what does it print without -static?

Comment: Now it's compilating. But I have this error : Program received signal `SIGBUS: Access to an undefined portion of a memory object.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7FAEE2D0A777
#1  0x7FAEE2D0AD7E
#2  0x7FAEE265CCAF
#3  0x400FCD in MAIN__ at fftg.f90:?`

Comment: That is some completely different problem. We cannot solve that here. The code might be wrong. Compile with `-g -Wall -fcheck=all`, run and ask a different question.